# como hacer vlookup en macros de dos libros de excel diferentes

Tags: vba, macros

Hola muy buenos días colegas, tengo una pregunta que aun no he podido resolver, resulta que tengo dos libros de excel A y B, en uno de ellos un registro como base de datos y en el otro una lista de códigos de productos y lo que quiero es buscar los datos en el libro B de acuerdo a los código del libro A con macros Vlookup alguna ayuda sera muy agradecido gracias!.
Aquí dejo unas lineas de codigo.
Application.CutCopyMode = False

```
conteo As Long
Dim Marca As Variant
Dim Rango As Variant
Dim Archivo As String
Dim bCarpeta As String
Dim codigoBuscado As String
Dim Final As Long

    bCarpeta = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Archivo = Dir(bCarpeta & "Maestro Dinet" & "*.xl*")
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Archivo
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Archivo = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Windows(Archivo).Activate

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'[Maestro Dinet.xlsb]01'!C1:C38,31,0)"
    Range("G5").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G5:G86") ', Type:=xlFillDefault

MsgBox "Proceso terminado", vbInformation, "Resultado"
```

Comment: Hola @Federico, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el código creado por el grabador de macros no funciona bien.

Intenta algo cómo esto:

```
With Sheets("Hoja_donde_aplicas_buscarv").Range("G5:G86")
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'" & Archivo & "01'!C1:C38,31,0)"
    .Formula = .Value
End With
```